# Neighbourhood in subset of a Metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Background: I was going through lec 11 of intro to real analysis series by Harvey mudd college and in the last part of this lecture prof. Francis su introduced relative openness. The series follows Principles of mathematical analysis by rudin. In this lecture he defines Neighbourhood in a metric space as follows:
A neighbourhood $N_r(x)$ in X is {$p \in X$ : d(x,p) <  r }

The question is as follows:

Consider a metric space $X$ and its subset Y then

1.) can we say that  an $\epsilon$ - Neighbourhood of some x w.r.t. Y is $N_\epsilon (x)\cap Y$ , where $N_\epsilon (x)$ is {p $\in$ X : d(p,x) < $\epsilon$}

2.) If we can define the neighbourhood as above would it be required that the corresponding x is in Y?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Of course you can *define* things - this is just giving things a name. What is questionable is whether the thing you've defined has any useful properties. My hunch is that there is more to this and there is some context around that question in this lecture that is absent in your question above. Is that lecture available online?

Comment: Yes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeVA74yivyg&list=PL04BA7A9EB907EDAF&index=12. I will rephrase my question

Comment: Watched the relevant portion of the video... I think there *is* an interesting case here: when *every* neighbourhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $Y$, such as intersections of neighbourhoods of $0$ in $\mathbb R$ with $(0,+\infty)\subseteq\mathbb R$ - then those neighbourhoods make up a *filter* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics) ) and so can be used to define *convergence* (such as $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)$).

Comment: So, with respect to your revised question above, I think the answer would be (1) Sure, you can give that object that name, this is basically the same as I said above; (2) No, there are useful cases where $x\not\in Y$ and the notion of "neighbours of $x$ in $Y$" make sense, so to speak. However, that part is a bit open-ended, different people will probably see different connections of this notion with different other things.